# Wordpress ajax function parameter not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am using wordpress ajax and following code not passing parameter value `metakey: id` to `$_POST["metakey"]`. So `var_dump($_POST)` shows `array(0) { }`

**if I enter static value of variable in PHP function `$key=<any meta key>` then its works fine**

```
jQuery(".selectbox").change(function(){
     var id = this.id;

     // do a POST ajax call
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
      data: ({
        action: "get-mata-value",        
        metakey: id
      }),
      success:  function( response ) {     
                jQuery.each(response ,function(index,value){
                    jQuery('#' +id).append('<option value="'+value+'">'+value+'</option>');
                });
 }
    });




});
```

PHP:

```
add_action("wp_ajax_get-mata-value", "get_mata_value");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_get-mata-value", "get_mata_value");
function get_mata_value()
{   
    global $wpdb;
$key=$_POST["metakey"];
    $result=
 $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( 
    "
    SELECT      DISTINCT meta_value
    FROM        $wpdb->postmeta 
    WHERE       meta_key = %s               
    ",
    $key
) ); 
 return($result);

    exit();

}
```

Comment: First of all, check in browser dev tools network panel, what parameters are send, to see if the problem is client- or server-side. And it looks like you are opening an SQL injection vulnerability here.

Comment: Is your php code executing at all? also your rresponse in "get_mata_value" is wrong, you are `returning` when you should be `echoing`. And putting an `exit` after a `return+` do not make any sense

Comment: @yivi PHP code working if I use static value in query

Comment: @CBroe no parameter named metakey listed there

Comment: I'm very sorry, but your code is **wrong**. The response to an ajax function should be an "echo", so you actually output something. If you `return` the value, it'll never reach your JS code. On top of that: does your PHP get executed? If so, post (in your question) the output of `vardump($_POST);`

Comment: if I change my query in php function as: SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = <any meta key>" then its works fine with same return and exit.

Comment: @yivi please provide me your solution as answer and I will accept it if it work able

Answer (score -1):

Did you try this?

```
data: (JSON.stringify({
    action: "get-mata-value",        
    metakey: id
})),
```